# when span change line the background-color style not work

Tags: javascript, html, css

In IE Edge, I want to change the `background-color` and `color` when the mouse hovers over the `<span>` element, but when the content is too long and wraps around at the end, the `background-color` does not work but color works well as following:

[image]

Comment: Add your code to the question, nobody will be able to help you without it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your css

```
.model-parameter-keyword-left span:hover{
      background: rgb(217,83,79);
      color: rgb(34,34,34);
}
```

Comment: I tried and it doesn't work, but when I add .label-danger class to the parent element, the .model-parameter-keyword's parent element,  it performs well, thank you all the same.